# Comparação de dados

Tags: php, mysql

**Meu cenário**: Eu peguei um código na internet que faz o parser do log da OpenVPN e joga no banco de dados para assim, jogar numa tabela numa página html. A saída é mais ou menos como essa: https://www.devco.net/code/openvpnStatusParser/openvpnstatus-sample.html
Esse parser analisa um arquivo de log que tem todos os clientes conectados.. Ele rodará a cada 5 minutos.

Pela página, poderá ser bloqueado uma **chave-cliente**.

O que eu pensei: parser analisa o log, joga numa tabela no banco com uma coluna status ativo (porque nesse log contém somente os clientes ativos). Criar uma outra tabela que vai conter os mesmos dados, porem se for bloqueado esta chave, colocar o status para bloqueado. E comparar as duas tabelas, se estiver bloqueado em uma e desbloqueado em outra, o resultado final será bloqueado. Aí um outro script vai rodar e bloquear a chave definitivamente (bloquear no firewall).

Porém eu não sei como fazer isso. Não sei se é melhor comparar em txt, melhor fazer a comparação no banco de dados... E se for uma das duas opções, eu não sei como fazer essa comparação.

Answer (score 0):

Tem algumas formas de resolver esse problema:

#### Duas tabelas, balance line

Duas tabelas. Dá `SELECT` em ambas as tabelas, simultaneamente, ordenando os registros pelos mesmos campos. Compara a chave dos dois registros "atuais" (que estão no topo). Se chave igual, você faz o teste negocial acima. Se diferente e registro "da esquerda" tem chave menor, ele só existe na tabela da esquerda, idem para tabela da direita, e faz os tratamentos com base nessa informação. Se chave igual avance para a próxima linha/registro em ambas as listas, se chave diferente avança o registro da chave menor.

Filtrar os dados (por data?) para não carregar a tabela toda.

#### Duas tabelas, SELECT na chave

O algoritmo que falou parece bem possível de implementar diretamente. `SELECT` dos registros ativos em um tabela, seguido de `SELECT` por chave na outra tabela. Tem de ser chave mesmo, primária ou ao menos com índice, senão o processamento será lento.

#### Uma tabela

Em vez de criar duas tabelas e ficar fazem mil consultas, cria uma só, contendo:

- Chave-cliente;
- Campos específicos que só existem na primeira tabela;
- Campos específicos que só existem na segunda tabela.

E alimenta essa tabela com os dados das duas fontes, tomando o cuidado de cada importação só mexer no "seu" campo específico. Assim basta um `SELECT` numa tabela só para saber a diferença ativo/bloqueado.

#### Qual escolher

O primeiro caso é mais apropriado a arquivos texto (que não tem tanta estrutura) ou massas grandes (tabelas histórico).

O segundo caso só funciona para tabelas mesmo, bem estruturadas (com índices), históricas ou não. Se forem históricas, tomar cuidado de pegar sempre o "último registro".

O terceiro caso é tirar a "junção" dos dados em memória e por numa tabela. Facilita porque separa o problema em três partes bem claras: importar dados da fonte 1, importar dados da fonte 2, pegar a diferença. Trabalhosa, não tão rápida, mas possivelmente a única que funciona para base de dados enormes (que não cabem em memória).